# Prove that $\sin X_n$ converges in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I need to show that knowing $X_n\rightarrow \pi$  converges in probability then $\sin X_n\rightarrow 0$ converges in probability.
So I need to show that:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(|\sin X_n|>\varepsilon)=0$$ for each $\varepsilon>0$. 
How can I do that? 
Idea:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n-\pi|\ge \varepsilon)=0$$
So:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n-\pi|\ge \varepsilon)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(X_n\ge\pi+ \varepsilon)+P(X_n\le\pi- \varepsilon)$$Probability is not negative so both needs to be zero.
Now let's take 
$P(\sin X_n\ge\sin(\pi+ \varepsilon))$and  $P(\sin(X_n)\le\sin(\pi- \varepsilon))$ Yet I am uncertain that I can do that. Couldn't that change inequality?
$\\$I will be glad for help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem

Comment: The most direct: $|\sin x|\leqslant|x-\pi|$ for every $x$ hence $$P(|\sin X_n|\geqslant\epsilon)\leqslant P(|X_n-\pi|\geqslant\epsilon)\to0$$

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: When radians are used, then $|\sin a-\sin b| \le |a-b|$ (with equality only when $a=b).$ When degrees are used, then $|\sin a - \sin b| \le \dfrac \pi {180} |a-b|. \qquad$

Answer (score 5):

A good thing to know is that $X_n \to X$ in probability if and only if for every subsequence $X_{n(m)}$ there's a subsubsequence $X_{n(m_k)}$ that converges almost surely to $X$.

In your case, that means for any subsequence $X_{n(m)}$ there's a subsubsequence $X_{n(m_k)} \to \pi$ a.s. Since sine is continuous, then $\sin(X_{n(m_k)}) \to \sin(\pi) = 0$ a.s. Now, we use the other direction of the "if and only if" to conclude that $\sin(X_n) \to 0$ in probability.

Note that nothing in that argument depends on the details of your problem. In general, if $X_n \to X$ in probability and $f$ is continuous, then $f(X_n) \to f(X)$ in probability.